# Character encoding errors with DynamicReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm having problems with character encodings with DynamicReports in Jasper Reports. I don't know where you should indicate the encoding.  There are problems with accented characters.  I have tried:

```
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING, "UTF-8"); //CP1252
exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
```

The screen capture linked to below shows that the characters are shown correctly in my code but not in the report.  How can I set the encoding in the report correctly?

[image: screen capture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today I had same problem, I will describe my solution.
My problem is not about encoding, it is about font.

DynamicReports create the pdf document with Helvetica font.
When I changed fontName to "DejaVu Serif", then problem was solved.

```
    StyleBuilder myStyle= stl.style().setPadding(2);
    myStyle.setFontName("DejaVu Serif");
    TextColumnBuilder<Double> weightCol = col.column("Ağırlığı", "weight", type.doubleType());
    weightCol.setStyle(myStyle);
```